# exsl:document not working properly

Tags: xml, perl, xslt, exslt

On Windows 7, I trying transform a single document using Perl v5.8.8 and libXSLT version 1.66. Here is the toned down version of my use case.

Perl Script

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Path;
use File::Spec;
use File::Basename;
use XML::LibXSLT;
use XML::LibXML;
use Getopt::Std;

my $isfile;

my ($xmlfile,$xsltfile,$samplefile) = qw/ Example.xml trans.xsl sample.xml/;
my %opts = ();
getopts('o:',\%opts);

my $outPath = $opts{'o'};
die "Resource Location/Directory not specified" if !defined($outPath);

if(-f $samplefile)
{
    $isfile = "true";
    print "File is present\n";
}
else
{
    $isfile = "false";
    print "File is absent\n";
}

my %args = ( "isfile" => $isfile,"outpath" => $outPath, );
my $xslt = XML::LibXSLT->new;
my $stylesheet = $xslt->parse_stylesheet_file($xsltfile);

     my $security = XML::LibXSLT::Security->new();
     $security->register_callback( read_file  => sub { return 1;} );
     $security->register_callback( write_file => sub { return 1;} );

     $stylesheet->security_callbacks( $security );

my $results  = $stylesheet->transform_file($xmlfile,XML::LibXSLT::xpath_to_string(%{args}));

0;
```

XSL File

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xslt" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" 
    xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times"
    extension-element-prefixes="exsl">

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" media-type="text/xml"/>

    <xsl:param name="isfile"/>
    <xsl:param name="outpath"/>

    <xsl:variable name="current-year">
        <xsl:value-of select="date:year()"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/">
         <xsl:if test="$isfile = 'true'">
                 <exsl:document href = "{$outpath}" method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes">
                 Article:- <xsl:value-of select="exsl:node-set(/Article/Title)|exsl:node-set(/Article/Title)/@context"/>
                Authors:- <xsl:apply-templates select="/Article/Authors/Author"/>
            </exsl:document>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

File to be transformed

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="xsl" href="trans.xsl"?>
<Article>
  <Title context="This article">My Article</Title>
  <Authors>
    <Author>Mr. Foo</Author>
    <Author>Mr. Bar</Author>
  </Authors>
  <Body>This is my article text.</Body>
</Article>
```

I create the directory beforehand where document needs to be generated. And then I run my script as follows

```
perl Transform.pl -o C:\user\Documents\XSLT\dir1\dir2\output1.xml
```

The file does not get created in the intended path. Instead, I get following when I do `DIR` or `ls` in my `XSLT` directory (where I keep my transformation script, xsl file and input xml file) ,

`%5Cuser%5CDocuments%5CXSLT%5Cdir1%5Cdir2%5Coutput1.xml  dir1/  Example.xml  sample.xml  Transform.pl  trans.xsl`

However, when I supply the path on the command line argument for option `-o`, as follows,

`C:\user\Documents\XSLT\dir1\dir2\output1.xml`

The file gets created in the appropriate supplied path.

1) Why is `exsl-document` acting weird when I supply the Windows specific path ?

2) Also, why is it adding `%5C` (which is ASCII equivalent of `/`) into the path?

3) Does it not understand how to interpret the Windows specific paths with path separator as `/` ?

Comment: I think `%5C` is `"\"` and not `"/"` and I think the problem is simply that you don't provide a URI but a path. So try using `-o file:///C:/user/Documents/XSLT/dir1/dir2/output1.xml`.